# React-Table v8 - cell value but not from the row?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have my array and I have no problem getting what I need using the accessorFn... but in the cell render I'm trying to populate a variable that is in another object and not in the data array used to by the react-table.

```
const defaultColumns = [
    {
      accessorKey: "Traveler",
      header: "Traveler",
      accessorFn: (row) => `${row.LTAGNAME} ${row.FTAGNAME} (${row.EMPNUM})`,
      cell: (props) => (
        <Link to={`/${group.ID}/registrant/${props.row.original.id}`}>
          {props.getValue()}
        </Link>
      ),

      size: 290,
    },
```

`{group.ID}` is a separate object in React unrelated to the data being passed into the useReactTable function. Is it possible to reference something outside of the "data" ?

Comment: did you figure this out? code example would be awesome if so!